# How to detect whether linger was reached when closing socket using ZeroMQ?

Tags: python, zeromq

The following `dispatch()` function runs receives messages through a `Queue.queue` and sends them using a ZeroMQ `PUSH` socket to an endpoint.

I want this function to exit, once it receives `None` through the queue, but if the socket's underlying message buffer has any undelivered messages (the remote endpoint is down), then the application won't terminate. Thus, once the function receives a `None`, it closes the socket with a specified linger.

Using this approach, how can I detect whether the specified linger was reached or not? In particular, no exception is raised.

```
def dispatch(self):    
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
    poller = zmq.Poller()

    socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555')
    poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLOUT)

    while True:
        try:
            msg = self.dispatcher_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.5)
        except queue.Empty:
            continue

        if msg is None:
            socket.close(linger=5000)
            break

        try:
            socket.send_json(msg)
        except Exception as exc:
            raise common.exc.WatchdogException(
                f'Failed to dispatch resource match to processor.\n{msg=}') from exc
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *"How to detect whether `linger` was reached when closing socket using ZeroMQ?"*

Well, not an easy thing.

ZeroMQ internally hides all these details from a user-level code, as the API was (since ever, till recent v4.3) crafted with all the beauties of the art of Zen-of-Zero, for the sake of maximum performance,  <sub>*almost*</sub> linear scaling and minimum latency. Do Zero-steps that do not support ( the less if violate ) this.

There might be three principal directions of attack on solving this:

- one may try to configure & use the event-observing overlay of `zmq_socket_monitor()` to analyse actual sequence of events on the lowest Level-of-Detail achievable
- one may also try a rather brute way to set infinite `LINGER` attribute for the `zmq.Socket()`-instance & directly kill the blocking operation by sending a `SIGNAL` after set amount of (now) soft-*"linger"* expired, be it using the new in v4.3+ features of `zmq_timers` ( a `[ms]`-coarse framework of timers / callback utilities ) or one's own
- one may prefer to keep things clean and still meeting the goal by "surrounding" a call to the `zmq_ctx_term()`, which as per v4.3 documented API will block ( be warned, that it is not warranted to be so in other API versions back & forth ). This way may help you indirectly detect a duration actually spent in blocking-state, like :

```
...
NOMINAL_LINGER_ON_CLOSE = 5000
MASK_a = "INF: .term()-ed ASAP, after {0:} [us] from {1:} [ms] granted"
MASK_b = "INF: .term()-ed ALAP, after {0:} [us] from {1:} [ms] granted"
...
socket.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, NOMINAL_LINGER_ON_CLOSE ) # ____ BE EXPLICIT, ALWAYS
aClk = zmq.Stopwatch()
aClk.start() #_________________________________________________ BoBlockingSECTION
context.term() # /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\   BLOCKING.......
_ = aClk.stop() #______________________________________________ EoBlockingSECTION
...
print( (      MASK_a if _ < ( NOMINAL_LINGER_ON_CLOSE * 1000 )
         else MASK_b
         ).format(      _,    NOMINAL_LINGER_ON_CLOSE )
       )
...
```

My evangelisation of always, indeed ***ALWAYS*** being rather EXPLICIT is based on both having seen the creeping *"defaults"*, that changed from version to version ( which is fair to expect to continue the same way forth ), so a responsible design shall, indeed ALWAYS, imperatively re-enter those very values, that we want to be in-place, as our code will survive both our current version & us, mortals, still having Zero-warranty of what part of our current assumptions will remain "defaults" in any future version / revision & having the same uncertainty what version-mix would be present in the domain of our deployed piece of code ( as of EoY-2020, there are still v2.1, v2.11, v3.x, v4.x running wild somewhere out there so one never knows, do we? )